# Using \texttt in an author block renders in italics

Tags: fonts, author

I have a document that has many uses of `{/tt some text}`, and I learned recently from reading this link: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd that apparently `{\tt ...}` is deprecated in favor of `\texttt{...}`. I've converted most of the document to use `\texttt{...}`, but when I try to update a block inside of an `author` tag the text renders in a weird font.

Original:

```
\author{
{\small My Name} \\
{\tt \small myEmail@stackexchange.com}
} % end author
```

With change:

```
\author{
{\small My Name} \\
\texttt{\small myEmail@stackexchange.com}
} % end author
```

In the original code, my email address renders in a nice, clean, teletype format. In the changed code, it renders in a pretty ugly italic format. That occurs with or without the `\small`.

Does anyone know if there is a supported way to render teletype font in an author block without rendering it in ugly italics?

Comment: You can use `{\upshape\ttfamily ...}`.

Comment: Thank you @Werner, that worked. Would you mind explaining why \texttt renders in Italics? I understand that using \upshape\ttfamily is a modal command - does \texttt choose a different default value for the shape or something?

Comment: The default behaviour (under `article`) is to print the author in an upright `t`ele`t`ype font. Are you using a special `\documentclass`?

Comment: Nothing too fancy: \documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tt` switches to `\normalfont` and therefore changes the font family, series and shape compared to `\texttt` (or `\ttfamily`) that just changes the font family.

To see this, use

```
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show #1}}
\pshow\tt
\pshow\normalfont
\pshow\texttt
```

Your `.log` should show

```
> \tt =\long macro:
->\@fontswitch {\normalfont \ttfamily }{\mathtt }.
\tt ->\protect \tt  

> \normalfont =\long macro:
->\usefont \encodingdefault \familydefault \seriesdefault \shapedefault \relax 
.
\normalfont ->\protect \normalfont  

> \texttt =\long macro:
#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\ttfamily #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}\tt
family \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi .
\texttt ->\protect \texttt
```

It's also obvious when using

```
\itshape something {\tt something} \texttt{somthing}
```

[image]